# How to identify the Postgres DB's pg restore command execution status?

Tags: postgresql

I see the state as "idle", Wait event as "Client: ClientRead" for more than 10 hrs.
I am not able to sense the activity, lively state of DB restoration. DB backup file size is ~25GB.

[image]

Comment: Odd, it should exit when it is done, not go idle.  What was the command line?  Was -j specified?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the full `pg_restore` command you are using as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) - [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please

Comment: One possibility could be a broken network that interrupted the connection. What does `pg_restore` say?